# Symfony 2 dump on object

Tags: php, symfony

when using the dump utility of symfony, there is a nice reference number that identifies the object such as `object: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#3491`, is there any way that one can get this value(3491) without without using the dump function. That is `some_function($object)` and then get the same number that symfony dump function would return.

Thanks

Comment: The [`VarDumper` docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/introduction.html) state that *#14 is the internal object handle. It allows comparing two consecutive dumps of the same object.* (`#14` is the number in the example.) [This seems to be the line](https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper/blob/master/Dumper/CliDumper.php#L259) where it's added to the resulting output. I don't *think* you can get the `Cursor` reference without extending the `HtmlDumper` class.

Comment: I know it's not why you asked for but ... every doctrine2 entity has an ID - why not just use that?

Comment: This ID is really internal stuff and should not be used or referenced from production code in any case. What is your concrete use-case for this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the [spl_object_hash](http://php.net/spl-object-hash)() value.

Comment: naah, I just test the output of `spl_object_hash()`, it returns `000000003579ded50000000144076b1c` when it should return `1336`